# need to run graphical Java app on Linux - how to resolve the libXt and libXm dependencies?

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries

I find myself with the uncommon task of running a very old graphical `java` app on `Linux` (`RHEL5`).  Of course, this app's `AWT` implementation is ultimately accommodated by a dependency on the `Linux X11` and `Motif` shared libraries.

Here is my error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/u935903/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Any suggestions re: how do I resolve this?

Do I just need to get the `64bit` compiled `libXtst.so.6` library and put it in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?  Where can I get this `64-bit.so` for `RHEL`?

Comment: This is kinda off-topic for SO but ... you'd install it just like any other library in RHEL; it should be available from your package manager.